# program in C which from a string of 10 numbers entered from the keyboard forms a string of elements whose values ​are in the range from 0 to 100

Tags: c

write a program in the language C which from a string of 10 numbers entered from the keyboard forms a string of elements whose values ​​are in the range from 0 to 100.

```
#define MAX 10
main()
{
    int niz[MAX],niz1[MAX],i;
    printf("Enter 10 numbers.\n");
    for(i=0; i<MAX; i++)
    scanf("%d",&niz[i]);
    printf("\nniz:\t");
    for(i=0; i<MAX; i++)
    printf("%d ",niz[i]);

    for(i=0; i<MAX; i++)
    {
        if(niz[i]>0 && niz[i]<100)
        niz1[i]=niz[i];
    }
    printf("\nNumbers in range 0-100:");
    for(i=0; i<MAX; i++) //i don't know what to put in here so the code can work i<???
    printf("%d ",niz1[i]);
} 
/*expecting outcome:
enter 1 2 -3 4 56 78 9 100 0 -76
niz:1 2 -3 4 56 78 9 100 0 -76
Numbers in range 0-100: 1 2 4 56 78 9 */
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the counter to calculate the number of values in range 0-100:

```
    int count = 0;
    for(i=0; i<MAX; i++)
    {
        if(niz[i]>0 && niz[i]<100) {
            niz1[count]=niz[i];
            count++;
        }
    }
```

Then when you print:

```
    printf("\nNumbers in range 0-100:");
    for(i=0; i<count; i++)
        printf("%d ",niz1[i]);
```

The complete program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX 10
int main()
{
    int niz[MAX],niz1[MAX],i;
    printf("Enter 10 numbers.\n");
    for(i=0; i<MAX; i++)
       scanf("%d",&niz[i]);
    printf("\nniz:\t");
    for(i=0; i<MAX; i++)
       printf("%d ",niz[i]);

    int count = 0;
    for(i=0; i<MAX; i++)
    {
        if(niz[i]>0 && niz[i]<100) {
            niz1[count]=niz[i];
            count++;
        }
    }
    printf("\nNumbers in range 0-100:");
    for(i=0; i<count; i++) 
       printf("%d ",niz1[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

The input and output:

```
1 2 3 -4 -5 6 -7 8 9 -10                                                                                                                      

niz:    1 2 3 -4 -5 6 -7 8 9 -10                                                                                                              
Numbers in range 0-100:1 2 3 6 8 9
```